# How to search Google Drive to find and Insert link to spefific Folder & File?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have an index spreadsheet, and not sure how to search and find Folder and File containing specific text related to values in column A and B.

In this spreadsheet, I create a product folder based on values from column A & B - `FolderName = ref + ' - ' + location` and store this inside one main parent folder.

Inside this new product folder, I then create a Google sheet with similar naming convention - `newDocName = ref + ' [Descriptions] - ' + location`

ref = value from column A
location = value from column B

'- Parent Folder
'-- Product Folder
'--- Product Sheet File

However, inside the index spreadsheet, I would like to auto-fill column L & M with the link to the new Folder & File that relates to that product.

Column L = Folder Link (Product Folder)
Column M = Sheet Link (Product Sheet File)

Can this be done inside the index spreadsheet, or would it need to be done with Google app script with an On Open trigger? If so, How can I use Google app script to search and fill in the relevant Folder & File GD Link to column L & M?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

If I understand correctly:

- A folder in your Drive contains a series of folders and files (inside the different child folders) whose titles depend on the values of columns A and B, according to the described conventions.
- You want to get the URL of the folders and files corresponding to each sheet row and write these to columns L and M, respectively.

#### Solution:

Create an Apps Script function to do the following:

- Get the parent folder via [DriveApp.getFoldersByName](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfoldersbynamename).
- Get the values from columns A and B, using [getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues).
- Iterate through the resulting values. For each row, retrieve the corresponding `folderName` and `sheetName` according to convention.
- Get the product folder name via [Folder.getFoldersByName](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getfoldersbynamename).
- Get the file name via [getFilesByName](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilesbynamename).
- Write the URLs to `L:M` via [setValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues).

#### Code sample:

```
const SHEET_NAME = "Sheet1"; // Add your sheet name
const PARENT_FOLDER_ID = "FOLDER_ID"; // Add your parent folder id
function writeUrls() {
  const parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(PARENT_FOLDER_ID);
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  const values = sheet.getRange("A2:B" + lastRow).getValues();
  const urls = values.map(([ref, location]) => {
    const folderName = `${ref} - ${location}`;
    const sheetName = `${ref} [Descriptions] - ${location}`;
    const foldersIter = parentFolder.getFoldersByName(folderName);
    let rowUrls = new Array(2);
    if (foldersIter.hasNext()) {
      const folder = foldersIter.next();
      rowUrls[0] = folder.getUrl();
      const filesIter = folder.getFilesByName(sheetName);
      if (filesIter.hasNext()) rowUrls[1] = filesIter.next().getUrl();
    }
    return rowUrls;
  });
  sheet.getRange("L2:M" + lastRow).setValues(urls);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Iamblichus for the code sample and solution walkthrough, very helpful and appears fairly straightforward. I set up and Run, Execution started and completed in log without any notice. Unfortunately, no desired result in terms of output of URLs. Although, what it did do was remove all the current content from L2:M and left a blank cell. I also tested with an On Open trigger as well, but same scenario.

Comment: @Ross The cells will remain blank if there's no child folder / file inside child folder with the requested names. I tested the code works and populates the URLs if these folders/files do exist, so please make sure that's the case for you. Also, if you want to run via `onOpen` trigger you will have to install the trigger, it will not be enough just to change the function name to `onOpen`, since this function requires authorization.

Answer (score 0):

I think for your purposes Drive API does exactly what you want. Enable Drive API in your script and run `Drive.Files.list()` method with search query. Something like that:

`Drive.Files.list({q: "fullText contains 'Example One'"});`

More info and options on [search query](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/search-files)